# Airflow fails to start. (ImportError: cannot import name 'mysql')

Tags: airflow

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 47, in command
    func = import_string(import_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 32, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/webserver_command.py", line 43, in <module>
    from airflow.www.app import cached_app, create_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 23, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import SQLA
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .api import ModelRestApi  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields import Related, RelatedList
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .schema import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .model_schema import ModelSchema, ModelSchemaOpts, ModelSchemaMeta
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/model_schema.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..convert import ModelConverter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql, mysql, mssql
ImportError: cannot import name 'mysql'
```

it started few days back but now it is not running.
installed mysql-connector
installed mysqlclient

`Tried everything but this error is not going.
[installed mysql but still getting the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Cgy.jpg)

Comment: could you share the system configuration you are using and the airflow version as well

Comment: i am using Centos 7 and airflow version 2.0.1

Comment: it seems like a dependency issue so could you check if you have the sqlalchemy package or not, using `pip show sqlalchemy`

Comment: pip show sqlalchemy
Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 1.3.22
Summary: Database Abstraction Library

Comment: could you add the marshmallow_sqlalchemy version details as well? also check if any virtualenv is being used?

Comment: pip show  marshmallow_sqlalchemy
Name: marshmallow-sqlalchemy
Version: 0.23.1
Summary: SQLAlchemy integration with the marshmallow (de)serialization library  (not using any virtualenv)